# Why do Leviathans have a taste for human flesh?

Tags: supernatural

Leviathan's were, in supernatural, Gods first animate creation. When they return in season 7, they start to chow down on human's pretty exclusively. I don't know if this sort of selectivity is common in invasive species, but it seems unusual.

I understand that humans must look like walking bags of tasty, but why not eat other things?

Comment: The rumor from the history books and from conversations with cannibals is that humans are simply delicious. Taste like ham or bacon or so it's said. Historically, called "long pork."

Comment: Sure, but when you're older than bacon, how do you know?

Comment: Personally, I think they eat humans as a means of pissing off their Maker. They seem perfectly willing to eat monsters, angels and each other when provoked. They even have the capacity to eat themselves (see bibbed). Who would design a creature that could consume itself completely? How do you do that, anyway? (see Nibblonians)

Comment: Which brings us to the real question: in a fight between the Niblonians and Leviathans, which would win out?

Comment: I think that all have matter with souls. What are Leviathans in myth and what are they in series? Eternal soul, pure energie is everything that matters to last two seasons. Maybe with eating humans they can "eat" soul to reistain on earth. And maybe simply because they are evil beings.

Comment: They say that human is the other white meat: http://atwitsendcomics.com/comics/index/111/Credible-Source

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe they eat people exclusively as much as humans are their most relevant (in terms of screen time) and most plentiful food. Humans have more meat than most animals approximately our size or smaller and we put up less of a fight than mist creatures equal to or bigger than ourselves. Then with out numbers in the 7 billion I would say we are the easiest and most plentiful meal.